Axios Requests to Rails Backend Returning 404 Instead of JSON Data
I'm working on a project where I have a Next.js frontend and a Rails backend. When I use Postman to make a GET request to http://localhost:3000/books, it works perfectly and returns the expected JSON data. However, when I try to make the same request using Axios from my Next.js frontend, I get a 404 error, and the response contains the HTML of my Next.js homepage instead of the JSON data from the Rails backend.
Here is my setup:
Next.js Axios Request:
export default async function HomePageConnected() {
  let data = null;
  axios.get("http://localhost:3000/books").then((response) => {
    data = response.data;
  });

  console.log("Data - " + data)

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome, you are connected</h1>
    </>
  )
}

Rails CORS Configuration (config/application.rb):
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:80'

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head],
             expose: ['Authorization']
  end
end

Rails Routes (config/routes.rb):
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
end

Additional Details:

Axios requests to external APIs (like GitHub) work fine from the
Next.js frontend.
The Rails server is running and accessible via Postman and browser.
When I check my nextjs server's log, I get a 404 error and within the data section, I get the homepage of my frontend server...
The 404 error is not even wrote within the backend logs, it is like if the request never reach the backend

Question:
What could be causing the Axios request from my Next.js frontend to return a 404 error instead of the expected JSON data from the Rails backend?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
PS: Here is my server error:
unhandledRejection: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
    at settle (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:618:71)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at Axios.request (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:57:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/books',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    _header: 'GET /books HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.7.0\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/books',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _events: [Object],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 404,
      statusMessage: 'Not Found',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      responseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/books',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 20,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _events: [Object],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/books',
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kChunkedBuffer)]: [],
    [Symbol(kChunkedLength)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kSocket)]: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _events: [Object],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      autoSelectFamilyAttemptedAddresses: [Array],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 3379877,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 580939,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 580936,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: [Object],
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: [Object],
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: [Object],
        [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 65536,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      'cache-control': 'no-store, must-revalidate',
      vary: 'RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch, Accept-Encoding',
      link: '</_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2>; rel=preload; as="font"; crossorigin=""; type="font/woff2"',
      'x-powered-by': 'Next.js',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      date: 'Mon, 20 May 2024 10:19:04 GMT',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'keep-alive': 'timeout=5',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object [AxiosHeaders]],
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/books',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      _header: 'GET /books HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.7.0\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/books',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kChunkedBuffer)]: [],
      [Symbol(kChunkedLength)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kSocket)]: [Socket],
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 65536,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1716200344318" data-precedence="next_static/css/app/layout.css"/><link rel="preload" as="script" fetchPriority="low" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1716200344318"/><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1716200344318" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js" async=""></script><meta name="robots" content="noindex"/><title>404: This page could not be found.</title><title>XXX</title><meta name="description" content="An app to share books with friends."/><meta name="next-size-adjust"/><script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" noModule=""></script></head><body class="__className_aaf875"><nav class="flex justify-between items-center p-4 navBar_navbar__KxV8N"><a href="/"><h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">XX</h1></a><ul class="space-x-4 navBar_menu__0oh4A"><li class="flex"></li><li class="flex"><button class="button navBar_phantomButton__Oq0Iz">login</button></li></ul><ul class="flex justify-evenly navBar_burger__dYBmF"><li><button class="">login</button></li></ul></nav><div style="font-family:system-ui,&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,&quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;,&quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;;height:100vh;text-align:center;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;justify-content:center"><div><style>body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}</style><h1 class="next-error-h1" style="display:inline-block;margin:0 20px 0 0;padding:0 23px 0 0;font-size:24px;font-weight:500;vertical-align:top;line-height:49px">404</h1><div style="display:inline-block"><h2 style="font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:49px;margin:0">This page could not be found.</h2></div></div></div><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1716200344318" async=""></script><script>(self.__next_f=self.__next_f||[]).push([0]);self.__next_f.push([2,null])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"1:HL[\\"/_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2\\",\\"font\\",{\\"crossOrigin\\":\\"\\",\\"type\\":\\"font/woff2\\"}]\\n2:HL[\\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1716200344318\\",\\"style\\"]\\n0:D{\\"name\\":\\"rQ\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"3:I[\\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js\\",[\\"app-pages-internals\\",\\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\\"],\\"\\"]\\n6:I[\\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js\\",[\\"app-pages-internals\\",\\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\\"],\\"\\"]\\n7:I[\\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js\\",[\\"app-pages-internals\\",\\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\\"],\\"\\"]\\n10:I[\\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js\\",[\\"app-pages-internals\\",\\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\\"],\\"\\"]\\n4:D{\\"name\\":\\"\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\n5:D{\\"name\\":\\"NotFound\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\n5:[[\\"$\\",\\"title\\",null,{\\"children\\":\\"404: This page could not be found.\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"div\\",null,{\\"style\\":{\\"fontFamily\\":\\"system-ui,\\\\\\"Segoe UI\\\\\\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\\\\\\"Apple Color Emoji\\\\\\",\\\\\\"Segoe UI Emoji\\\\\\"\\",\\"height\\":\\"100vh\\",\\"textAlign\\":\\"center\\",\\"display\\":\\"flex\\",\\"flexDirection\\":\\"column\\",\\"alignItems\\":\\"center\\",\\"justifyContent\\":\\"center\\"},\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"div\\",null,{\\"children\\":[[\\"$\\",\\"style\\",null,{\\"dangerouslySetInnerHTML\\":{\\"__html\\":\\"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}\\"}}],[\\"$\\",\\"h1\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"next-error-h1\\",\\"style\\":{\\"display\\":\\"inline-block\\",\\"margin\\":\\"0 20px 0 0\\",\\"padding\\":\\"0 23px 0 0\\",\\"fontSize\\":24,\\"fontWeight\\":500,\\"verticalAlign\\":\\"top\\",\\"lineHeight\\":\\"49px\\"},\\"children\\":\\"404\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"div\\",null,{\\"style\\":{\\"display\\":\\"inline-block\\"},\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"h2\\",null,{\\"style\\":{\\"fontSize\\":14,\\"fontWeight\\":400,\\"lineHeight\\":\\"49px\\",\\"margin\\":0},\\"children\\":\\"This page could not be found.\\"}]}]]}]}]]\\n8:D{\\"name\\":\\"RootLayout\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\n9:D{\\"name\\":\\"NavBar\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\na:D{\\"name\\":\\"NotFound\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\nb:{\\"fontFamily\\":\\"system-ui,\\\\\\"Segoe UI\\\\\\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,\\\\\\"Apple Color Emoji\\\\\\",\\\\\\"Segoe UI Emoji\\\\\\"\\",\\"height\\":\\"100vh\\",\\"textAlign\\":\\"center\\",\\"dis"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"play\\":\\"flex\\",\\"flexDirection\\":\\"column\\",\\"alignItems\\":\\"center\\",\\"justifyContent\\":\\"center\\"}\\nc:{\\"display\\":\\"inline-block\\",\\"margin\\":\\"0 20px 0 0\\",\\"padding\\":\\"0 23px 0 0\\",\\"fontSize\\":24,\\"fontWeight\\":500,\\"verticalAlign\\":\\"top\\",\\"lineHeight\\":\\"49px\\"}\\nd:{\\"display\\":\\"inline-block\\"}\\ne:{\\"fontSize\\":14,\\"fontWeight\\":400,\\"lineHeight\\":\\"49px\\",\\"margin\\":0}\\na:[[\\"$\\",\\"title\\",null,{\\"children\\":\\"404: This page could not be found.\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"div\\",null,{\\"style\\":\\"$b\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"div\\",null,{\\"children\\":[[\\"$\\",\\"style\\",null,{\\"dangerouslySetInnerHTML\\":{\\"__html\\":\\"body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}\\"}}],[\\"$\\",\\"h1\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"next-error-h1\\",\\"style\\":\\"$c\\",\\"children\\":\\"404\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"div\\",null,{\\"style\\":\\"$d\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"h2\\",null,{\\"style\\":\\"$e\\",\\"children\\":\\"This page could not be found.\\"}]}]]}]}]]\\n8:[\\"$\\",\\"html\\",null,{\\"lang\\":\\"en\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"body\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"__className_aaf875\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$L9\\",[\\"$\\",\\"$L6\\",null,{\\"parallelRouterKey\\":\\"children\\",\\"segmentPath\\":[\\"children\\"],\\"error\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"errorStyles\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"errorScripts\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"template\\":[\\"$\\",\\"$L7\\",null,{}],\\"templateStyles\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"templateScripts\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"notFound\\":\\"$a\\",\\"notFoundStyles\\":[],\\"styles\\":null}]]}]}]\\nf:D{\\"name\\":\\"\\",\\"env\\":\\"Server\\"}\\n11:[]\\n0:[[[\\"$\\",\\"link\\",\\"0\\",{\\"rel\\":\\"stylesheet\\",\\"href\\":\\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1716200344318\\",\\"precedence\\":\\"next_static/css/app/layout.css\\",\\"crossOrigin\\":\\"$undefined\\"}]],[\\"$\\",\\"$L3\\",null,{\\"buildId\\":\\"development\\",\\"assetPrefix\\":\\"\\",\\"initialCanonicalUrl\\":\\"/books\\",\\"initialTree\\":[\\"\\",{\\"children\\":[\\"/_not-found\\",{\\"children\\":[\\"__PAGE__\\",{}]}]},\\"$undefined\\",\\"$undefined\\",true],\\"initialSeedData\\":[\\"\\",{\\"children\\":[\\"/_not-found\\",{\\"children\\":[\\"__PAGE__\\",{},[[\\"$L4\\",\\"$5\\"],null],null]},[\\"$\\",\\"$L6\\",null,{\\"parallelRouterKey\\":\\"children\\",\\"segmentPath\\":[\\"children\\",\\"/_not-found\\",\\"children\\"],\\"error\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"errorStyles\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"errorScripts\\":\\"$undefined"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"\\",\\"template\\":[\\"$\\",\\"$L7\\",null,{}],\\"templateStyles\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"templateScripts\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"notFound\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"notFoundStyles\\":\\"$undefined\\",\\"styles\\":null}],null]},[\\"$8\\",null],null],\\"couldBeIntercepted\\":false,\\"initialHead\\":[[\\"$\\",\\"meta\\",null,{\\"name\\":\\"robots\\",\\"content\\":\\"noindex\\"}],\\"$Lf\\"],\\"globalErrorComponent\\":\\"$10\\",\\"missingSlots\\":\\"$W11\\"}]]\\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"12:I[\\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js\\",[\\"app/layout\\",\\"static/chunks/app/layout.js\\"],\\"\\"]\\n13:I[\\"(app-pages-browser)/./app/_components/login.tsx\\",[\\"app/layout\\",\\"static/chunks/app/layout.js\\"],\\"default\\"]\\nf:[[\\"$\\",\\"meta\\",\\"0\\",{\\"name\\":\\"viewport\\",\\"content\\":\\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"meta\\",\\"1\\",{\\"charSet\\":\\"utf-8\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"title\\",\\"2\\",{\\"children\\":\\"XXX\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"meta\\",\\"3\\",{\\"name\\":\\"description\\",\\"content\\":\\"An app to share books with friends.\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"meta\\",\\"4\\",{\\"name\\":\\"next-size-adjust\\"}]]\\n4:null\\n9:[\\"$\\",\\"nav\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"flex justify-between items-center p-4 navBar_navbar__KxV8N\\",\\"children\\":[[\\"$\\",\\"$L12\\",null,{\\"href\\":\\"/\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"h1\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"text-2xl font-bold\\",\\"children\\":\\"XXX\\"}]}],[[\\"$\\",\\"ul\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"space-x-4 navBar_menu__0oh4A\\",\\"children\\":[[\\"$\\",\\"li\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"flex\\"}],[\\"$\\",\\"li\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"flex\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"$L13\\",null,{\\"text\\":\\"login\\",\\"className\\":\\"button navBar_phantomButton__Oq0Iz\\"}]}]]}],[\\"$\\",\\"ul\\",null,{\\"className\\":\\"flex justify-evenly navBar_burger__dYBmF\\",\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"li\\",null,{\\"children\\":[\\"$\\",\\"$L13\\",null,{\\"text\\":\\"login\\",\\"className\\":\\"\\"}]}]}]]]}]\\n"])</script></body></html>'


Can you share more details about the error? also is it possible that it's CORS related?

I added the error message, and I do not think it is a core issue

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/books")
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("Data - ", data);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome, you are connected</h1>
    </>
  );
}```

try this in react, it's the correct approach of fetching data.
Also are you sure that your front is running on Port 80 and back on 3000?
